# HTML src is not properly changing

Tags: html

I don't know why someone removed my edit. The suggested change did infact work. Soooo, gonna add it again.

**EDIT**

It was just a silly mistake where I forgot to reference the array image's source

*whoops*

**EDIT**

So at my job we teach coding to kids. I'm mostly a Unity(C#) instructor, but today I'm subbing for HTML. 
This kid wants to have an animation play as you scroll down the page.

My intentions with this code is to keep as much of the logic centered around what he has already learned. So switching the image source every once in a while based off y position seemed like a good choice.

I know I am missing something simple, but for some reason my code can't reference the images within my array correctly.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body onscroll="myFunction()">

<h2>Sticky Image: Scroll Down to See the Effect</h2>
<p>The image will "stick" to the screen when you reach its scroll position.</p>

<img id="navbar" class="sticky" src = "https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/192-1922718_hehe-xd-fat-chocobo-sprite.png">

<h2>Scroll Down</h2>
<p>Some example text..</p>
<p><b>Scroll back up again to "remove" the sticky position.</b></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

<script>
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var ani = false;

var imgArray = new Array();
var counter = 0;

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = "https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/192-1922718_hehe-xd-fat-chocobo-sprite.png";

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-walking-walk-sign-flat-260nw-1253968402.jpg";

function myFunction() {
  if(window.pageYOffset % 100 > 95 && ani == false)
  {
      ani = true;
      counter = counter + 1;
      navbar.src = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length]
      console.log("counter: " + counter +"Array: "+(counter % imgArray.length));
  }
  if(window.pageYOffset % 100 < 95)
  {
      ani = false;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's mostly just a bunch of w3school examples combined with the intention of testing the logic out before I teach it. I'm testing it in the app SoloLearn if that info helps at all

The weirdest part is `imgArray[0]` is the same exact image link as what was initially set. And the initial image works perfectly fine. It stops showing as soon as my if statement triggers though.

If I can't get this to work, I'll simply teach him stuff I know works. But I really wanted to get this concept working since it was mentioned the kid wanted to add this in the notes. 
And it's seriously bugging me that I keep looking at it and not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at the errors in developer console? (F12 in Chrome)

Comment: I don't have a computer of my own, so I have been coding through an app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> navbar.src = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length]
> ```

Your array contains *image* objects.

The `src` property expects a URL.

```
navbar.src = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length].src
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.src` part.

`navbar.src = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length].src;`

Other than that its working fine:

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var ani = false;

var imgArray = new Array();
var counter = 0;

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = "https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/192-1922718_hehe-xd-fat-chocobo-sprite.png";

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-walking-walk-sign-flat-260nw-1253968402.jpg";

function myFunction() {
  if(window.pageYOffset % 100 > 95 && ani == false)
  {
      ani = true;
      counter = counter + 1;
      navbar.src = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length].src;
      console.log("counter: " + counter +"Array: "+(counter % imgArray.length));
  }
  if(window.pageYOffset % 100 < 95)
  {
      ani = false;
  }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onscroll = myFunction;
```

```css
img.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sticky Image: Scroll Down to See the Effect</h2>
<p>The image will "stick" to the screen when you reach its scroll position.</p>

<img id="navbar" class="sticky" src = "https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/192-1922718_hehe-xd-fat-chocobo-sprite.png">

<h2>Scroll Down</h2>
<p>Some example text..</p>
<p><b>Scroll back up again to "remove" the sticky position.</b></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
```